# How do I decide whether a component should have its own reducer function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do I decide whether a component should have its own reducer function, or delegate to an ancestor component?

For example:

I have a `HomePage` component with a reducer function that is registered with the store when the page is visited via the router.

The `HomePage` component contains within it an instance of a `Grid` component.

```
<div>
  <Grid contents={contents} />
</div>
```

The `Grid` component needs to recalculate the number columns it uses when the viewport is resized, so I add an action associated with the `Grid` named `UPDATE_COLUMN_COUNT`.

A call to dispatch this action is bound to the `window` `resize` event in the `onComponentDidMount` of `Grid`.

For `Grid`, where should I register its reducer with the store?

Should I register it manually in the router (together with the existing registration of the `HomePage` reducer)?

Should I somehow combine the reducer for `HomePage` with the reducer for `Grid`?

Or should I respond to the `UPDATE_COLUMN_COUNT` action in the `HomePage` reducer and not have a reducer for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use the local component state for this rather than storing in my Redux store. This is a purely display concern that will not affect any other component so I don't want to over complicate my code.

If this number of columns could be used throughout the application by different components then you might want to put it in the Redux state.

Generally, the application state should be loosely coupled from the components you use, i.e. you don't try to map components to reducers. Instead, you create the relevant application state by composing your reducers and select the relevant parts for each component.